# Why the Theme breakpoints in MUI is not working?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am learning about MUI and got this error. The purpose of the code is to be responsive. Thank you very much.

[Link CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hook-material-demo-forked-ij19y?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 3):

In v5, `ThemeProvider` should be defined at the root of your application and `useStyles` should not be called before `ThemeProvider`

[Reference link](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#themeprovider-setup)

[Referenced Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-roman-i7gmm?file=/src/index.js)

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  ThemeProvider,
  createTheme,
  StyledEngineProvider
} from "@mui/material/styles";

import Demo from "./demo";
const theme = createTheme();

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <Demo />
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
    color: "white",
    height: 48,
    padding: "0 30px",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
      padding: "40px"
    }
  }
}));

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Styled with Hook API</Button>;
}
```

**Using styled component API**

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const MyButton = styled("button")(({ theme }) => ({
  background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
  color: "white",
  height: 48,
  padding: "0 30px",
  [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
    background: "blue"
  }
}));

export default function Hook() {
  return <MyButton>something</MyButton>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. All the best to you !

Answer (score 0):

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';


const useStyles = styled((theme) => ({
  root: {
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
    color: "white",
    height: 48,
    padding: "0 30px",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
      height: 100
    }
  }
}));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. All the best to you !